# How to automate moving words in excel in the same column

Tags: excel, automation

I'm not good with excel, my knowledge is very limited, but I'm stuck with a project where I have 3,077 rows. There are a few columns where I need to move around a few words or numbers. All I need right now is to know how to do it in one column, or if it's even possible. I have a list of addresses and 90% of them have been entered incorrectly. Rather than go through each one one by one I'm hoping there's something I can run to swap the word or number around. If need be I can create a new column.

Below is an example. The first two are correct, the next four are not. I need the second number to be after ROAD or after HWY. i.e. 6 ROAD 3066 or 1059 HWY 516. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
42 ROAD 3050
68 ROAD 3400
6 3066 ROAD
1059 516 HWY
986 516 HWY
33 3403 ROAD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your task is as follows:

- your have three columns
- one of them is not a number
- you want to have them in order number/text/number

Your input cells are A1/B1/C1. Then create the following additional columns:

- `D1 = IF(ISNUMBER(A1);A1;B1)`
- `E1 = IF(ISNUMBER(A1);IF(ISNUMBER(C1);B1;C1);A1)`
- `F1 = IF(ISNUMBER(C1);C1;B1)`

Those are then the desired output columns.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify. I have one column with the above data. In this column I need to move road or HWY (or the road number). So, it's already all in the same column and I need to keep it in the same column. If I need to create three columns and then combine them back into one column that would work too. Thank you.

Comment: @Evan: Split them by "Text To Columns", apply above transformation and then combine them again into one column.